# Changing the version control in IDEA IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I've changed from Git to SVN the folders which contains the project's code, but IntelliJ seems the same as before so I can't work with SVN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+S (Project Settings) -> Version Control

It should list the project directory and what VCS it's using. Change it there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice document regarding the issues with several Version Control Systems:

[IntelliJ Site](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html#Git_support)